# Are deleted sms are still in content://sms?

Tags: android

I'm working on kind of project that uses sms and call_logs.
I want to know if deleted sms(call_logs) are still in content://sms database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why should there be still there if you delete them?

Smses and call logs are stored in the database and to modify them you need to use content provider. content provider will get your request and execute a query on the database. so when you deleting a sms a delete query will run on the database and data will be deleted for ever!

Comment: What i'm trying to say is : is android system store the deleted data in some place that you can restore (images used to restore the deleted files) ? Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

No, sms and mms are removed from content provider once they deleted..and msg_id of deleted sms will also be assigned to a new msg next time

Comment: "msg_id of deleted sms will also be assigned to a new msg" Source?